# Modelstate always complains of invalid datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modelstate

I have added this data annotation in one of the properties of my model

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? LastLoginDate { get; set; }
```

However, whenever I save my data from edit mode, the model state always says the date is invalid IF the day is greater than 12.

E.g.,

01/12/2012 (Valid)
31/12/2012 (Invalid)

How do I correct this such that 31/12/2012 is recognized as valid by the modelstate.

Comment: can you show how you have the Attributes defined if any ..something like this for example 
`[Display(Name = "Test Date")]`
`[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]`
`[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]`
`public Nullable<DateTime> test_date { get; set; }`

Comment: does the example I put in the comment work `public Nullable<DateTime>`

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Isn't Nullable and ? the same?